# What is the max number of async threads created for kafkatemplate async response

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-kafka, forkjoinpool

"A ForkJoinPool is constructed with a given target parallelism level; by default, equal to the number of available processors."

Suppose my CPU has 2 cores. So, the number of max threads created by ForkJoinPool is 4?

Suppose I am performing an asynchronous operation which returns a future object in a loop (say 10k) operation which uses default Forkpool... then how many threads will be created by Forkpool?

```java
List<ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>>> cf = new ArrayList<ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>>>();

future = kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, message);
cf.add(future);

i++;

future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, String>>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, String> result) {
        syso("sent success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println(" sending failed");
    }
});
```

And, in some other class, I am checking if all future have completed or not:

```java
    for (ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> m : myFutures) {
        m.get();
    }
```

Comment: have you tried it ? If thread is not available that task will be added to queue, can you show the code ?

Comment: I have added the code.....I am sending the message(say 10k msgs)  to Kakfa asychronously and waiting future to complete . Suppose all my futures are in pending state ...so how many threads will be created ?

Comment: You didn't say where you got these docs from and what they are referring to, but are you asking if the docs are correct? If you have 2 CPU cores, then 2 threads would be created. The exception here is something like Intel Hyperthreading, which the OS will treat as additional processors. So based on the behavior you describe, it may be more accurate to state that `numThreads = numLogicalCores`

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider i got it from .But my doubt is if i am performing an async operation which returns a future in loop like shown in code and it uses default FirkJoinPool then how many max threads could be created by ForkJoinPool..https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html

Comment: You don't show any code using a `ForkJoinPool`. Getting a `Future<?>` from the template does not spawn any new threads; it is simply completed by the producer's IO thread.

Comment: @GaryRussell yes because i am using ListenableFuture which uses the default Common/For pool.I am not defining it anywhere

Comment: @GaryRussell ia m just wondering what issues ccan i have if suppose i am waiting for all 10k futures at onces...apart from 10k future objects......any thread related issue can i face?

Comment: @GaryRussell I have a question here, messages are sent in batches into Kafka topic right by using producers IO threads? suppose if that batch has `10` records then that single thread is responsible to make 10 async response calls ?

Comment: ? `ListenableFuture` is an interface; even implementations of it are inactive objects that start no threads. The template returns a `SettableListenerFuture` which is completed when the results come back from Kafka - there is no threading involved.

Comment: @Deadpool - yes; that's what I see.

Comment: @GaryRussell thanks this clears my doubt.We are going to use kafka with spring at my work

Comment: Thank you so much @GaryRussell

Comment: @Deadpool I added an example in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no additional threading; the futures are completed on the producer's I/O thread.

Here is a test that shows the callbacks...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So61415751Application {


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So61415751Application.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So61415751Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        template.setProducerListener(new ProducerListener<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord, RecordMetadata recordMetadata) {
                LOG.info(recordMetadata.toString());
            }
        });
        return args -> {
            IntStream.range(0, 9).forEach(i -> template.send("so61415751", "foo" + i));
            LOG.info("Sent");
            Thread.sleep(10_000);
        };
    }


    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so61415751").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.producer.properties.linger.ms=3000

#logging.level.org.springframework.kafka=debug

logging.level.org.apache.kafka=debug
```

result

```
2020-04-24 17:27:46.282  INFO 96084 --- [           main] com.example.demo.So61415751Application   : Sent

...

3 second linger

...

2020-04-24 17:27:49.299  INFO 96084 --- [ad | producer-1] com.example.demo.So61415751Application   : so61415751-0@63
2020-04-24 17:27:49.300  INFO 96084 --- [ad | producer-1] com.example.demo.So61415751Application   : so61415751-0@64
2020-04-24 17:27:49.300  INFO 96084 --- [ad | producer-1] com.example.demo.So61415751Application   : so61415751-0@65
2020-04-24 17:27:49.300  INFO 96084 --- [ad | producer-1] com.example.demo.So61415751Application   : so61415751-0@66
2020-04-24 17:27:49.300  INFO 96084 --- [ad | producer-1] com.example.demo.So61415751Application   : so61415751-0@67
2020-04-24 17:27:49.300  INFO 96084 --- [ad | producer-1] com.example.demo.So61415751Application   : so61415751-0@68
2020-04-24 17:27:49.300  INFO 96084 --- [ad | producer-1] com.example.demo.So61415751Application   : so61415751-0@69
2020-04-24 17:27:49.301  INFO 96084 --- [ad | producer-1] com.example.demo.So61415751Application   : so61415751-0@70
2020-04-24 17:27:49.301  INFO 96084 --- [ad | producer-1] com.example.demo.So61415751Application   : so61415751-0@71
```

(The thread the calls the `ProducerListener` also completes the future).